# C# inserting to SQL with ODBC connection syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, odbc

I want to insert rows every interval in c#. I'm getting this error:

> [42000][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] incorrect
>   syntax near ';'.

Here is the code:

```
cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n}" + "VALUES (?, ?);";
using (OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand())
{
    comm.Connection = connection;
    comm.CommandText = cmdString;
    comm.Parameters.Add("value", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int).Value = value;
    comm.Parameters.Add("time", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    rows += 1;
}
```

please help

**EDIT**

Now everything seems to be ok, but I can't see the rows appear in the tables in sql server :/ Can you please help me with that too? here is my connectionstring:

```
connetionString = "Driver={Sql Server}; Server=baxu\\sqlexpress; Database = baza1;" + $"UID ={ username };PWD={ password };";
```

Comment: Is that `;` right after `(?, ?)` needed?

Comment: You need a space before `VALUES` otherwise your query will be `INSERT INTO tablenameVALUES (...` etc

Comment: no need to concatenate strings. This will do: `cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n} VALUES (?, ?);"`

Comment: thanks a lot it worke Diado and Nino :))

Answer (score 1):

Your command string is false, missing space before values. So, instead of

```
cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n}" + "VALUES (?, ?);";
```

do this:

```
cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n} VALUES (?, ?);";
```

or, if you insist in concatenation:

```
cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n}" + " VALUES (?, ?);";
//notice the space here ----------^
```

also, check if `n` contains existing table name

Answer (score 0):

Depend on n value, you will have different cmdString. Probably, n contains table name without space, so, resulting sting will have table name and value glued together.
Check value of cmdString in debugger (or output it to log).